# How to check if column exists in the Datarow

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to check if column exists in the datarow before binding it but column.contains property not working. Don’t know what I am missing here.

Here is the code:

```
 Private Sub Bind(ByRef reader As SqlDataReader)
    Dim dt As DataTable = reader.GetSchemaTable

    list = New List(Of Employees)

    For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
        BindObject(r)
        list.Add(obj)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub BindObject(ByRef dr As DataRow)
  obj = New Employees
  If dr.Table.Columns.Contains("ID") Then obj.VisitID = CType(dr("ID"), Integer) 
End Sub
```

**Solution:**

This following solution provided by @ajakblackgoat works absolutely fine.

```
 If dt.Select("ColumnName='ID'").Count = 1 Then obj.VisitID = CType(dr("ID"), Integer)
```

I have come up with other two solutions and it might help others.

**Alternate Solution I:**

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = reader.GetSchemaTable

    Dim columns = New List(Of String)()

    For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
        columns.Add(reader.GetName(i))
    Next

    If columns.Contains("ID") Then obj.ID = CType(dr("ID"), Integer)
```

**Alternate Solution II:**

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt.Load(reader)

    If dr.Table.Columns.Contains("ID") Then obj.VisitID = CType(dr("ID"), Integer)
```

Comment: For starters, you didn't post your `BindObjectV2` method.  That seems relevant to your question.

Comment: `Columns.Contains` works fine and is not case sensitive. Are you such a column exists? Try to debug you code.

Comment: datarow item array (0) does contain 'ID'

Comment: What happens when you itterate through each column and output it's name.

Comment: `For Each cl as DataColumn in dr.Table.Columns ... system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(cl.ColumnName) ... Next`

Comment: i get 'ColumnName' 'ColumnOrdinal' 'ColumnSize'. It is not giving column names.

Comment: This code works fine; Dim columns = New List(Of String)()

        For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
            columns.Add(reader.GetName(i))
        Next

        If columns.Contains("AssignmentID") Then

        End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `reader.GetSchemaTable` returns all columns information of the reader. So you have to find the column name as record instead of column.

Use the below code to check if the column name exists in the reader:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = dr.GetSchemaTable

If dt.Select("ColumnName='ID'").Count = 1 Then
    ' column name exists
End If
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Do you think it is efficient than Dim dt As DataTable  dt.Load(reader)

Comment: It's not comparable. You should be aware that `GetSchemaTable` is a totally different from `Load`. `GetSchemaTable` loads a datatable with the schema info of the reader (ie. list of column names, data types, etc), whereas `Load(reader)` simply loads the datatable with records returned from the reader from database.